# How to show new question while hiding previous questions after keypress has been called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a math game with different arithmetic functionalities. Given that I am new to JQuery, I am having trouble showing only the current question and hiding all of the previous ones that have been answered by the user.

I have separated the functions in order to improve the modularity of the content but I am still having trouble showing & hiding content.

```js
var firstOperation = "ADD";
var upRange = 10;
var questiNum = 10;

var max = parseInt(upRange);
var min = 0;
var questRight = 0;
var quantQuest = 0;

$(function() {
  var operators = setOperator(firstOperation);
   var num1 = getRandomInt(min, max);
   var num2 = getRandomInt(min, max);
   displayQuestion(num1, num2, operators);
   checkQuest(num1, num2, operators);
  }

});

function setOperator(firstOperation) {
  if (firstOperation === "ADD") {
    console.log("setOperation: ADD");
    return '+';
  } else if (firstOperation === "SUBTRACT") {
    console.log("setOperation: SUBTRACT");
    return '-';
  } else if (firstOperation === "MULTIPLY") {
    console.log("setOperation: MULTIPLY");
    return '*';
  } else if (firstOperation === "DIVIDE") {
    console.log("setOperation: DIVIDE");
    return '/';
  } else {
    return alert("Operator did not work!!");
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function displayQuestion(num1, num2, operators) {
  $('#question').html(num1 + ' ' + operators + ' ' + num2 + ' = ');
}

function checkQuest(num1, num2, operators) {
  $('#question-answer').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('#question-answer').attr('disabled', true);
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      $(this).after(function() {
        if (eval(num1 + operators + num2) == $('#question-answer').val()) {
          questRight++;
          console.log("RIGHT!!!" + questRight);
        }

      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-section">
  <div id="questionbox">
    <p id="question">&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="answerbox">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="question-answer" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a bunch of localStorage.getItem() calls, but where exactly do you run localStorage.setItem()?

Comment: I have them from a previous HTML page. They are all working, the issue is being able to show the questions one at a time.

Comment: OK, but we are missing a crucial part here in order to test the code ourselves.

Comment: You’re right, I have removed the localStorage for readability

Comment: So, at first, you want all 10 questions to be displayed, right?

Comment: Please check out how to create an [mcve].  This is way more code than necessary to parse through in order to reproduce the problem...

Comment: I want to only display one question at a time. The goal is for the user to input however many questions they want to answer and only display one at a time until the quantity is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited - after comments.

The problem is that you are not calling the function to "reload" a question.

This altered code snippet will insert will call the "loadNextQuestion" method, after each key press.

I moved the random numbers into global use, so you can use the same event.

Also no need for the disable.

```js
var firstOperation = "ADD";
var upRange = 10;
var questiNum = 10;

var max = parseInt(upRange);
var min = 0;
var questRight = 0;
var quantQuest = 0;

//make them global
var num1;
var num2;
var operators;

$(function() {
  loadNextQuestion();
  addCheckQuestEvent(operators, quantQuest);
});

function loadNextQuestion() {
  operators = setOperator(firstOperation);
  num1 = getRandomInt(min, max);
  num2 = getRandomInt(min, max);
  displayQuestion(quantQuest);
}

function setOperator(firstOperation) {
  if (firstOperation === "ADD") {
    console.log("setOperation: ADD");
    return '+';
  } else if (firstOperation === "SUBTRACT") {
    console.log("setOperation: SUBTRACT");
    return '-';
  } else if (firstOperation === "MULTIPLY") {
    console.log("setOperation: MULTIPLY");
    return '*';
  } else if (firstOperation === "DIVIDE") {
    console.log("setOperation: DIVIDE");
    return '/';
  } else {
    return alert("Operator did not work!!");
  }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function displayQuestion() {
  var containerQuestion = $('#question');
  containerQuestion.text(`${num1} ${operators} ${num2} =`);
}

function addCheckQuestEvent() {
  $(`#question-answer`).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $(this).after(function() {
        if (eval(num1 + operators + num2) == $(`#question-answer`).val()) {
          questRight++;
          console.log("RIGHT!!!" + questRight);
        }
        quantQuest++;
        if (quantQuest<10) {
          loadNextQuestion();
        }
        else {
          alert(`bye bye, you answered: ${questRight} `);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-section">
  <div id="questionbox">
  <p id="question"></p>
    <div id="answerbox">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="question-answer" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But wouldn’t this just append the newest question at the bottom? The previous questions would be displayed above. The goal is to have only one question being displayed at a time and in the end; inform the user how many they missed.

Comment: @JohnSalazar why are you looping all the questions in the beginning then?

Comment: I forgot to remove it from the original code, I have removed it now. The idea behind that was to see if I could pause the loop until it read an input from the user and hide/show the question but I realized, it doesn’t work like that.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @Papageno np, glad to help. Please mark as answer if my answer helped you.